# Adobe Reader for linux

Tags: linux, adobe-acrobat

Currently Adobe Acrobat Reader for Linux is at version 9.5.5.  Does anybody know when Adobe is going to release a version 10 or 11 and have the ability to use a Reader Extension enabled PDF file?

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a Linux version of Adobe Acrobat Pro that I need to enable Reader Extensions with.  I am currently setting it with a Windows version.

Comment: Have you tried running it in wine?  Versions 8.0 and 9.0 Professional are rated platinum.  Version 9.0 Pro Extended is rated gold.  Version X Pro is rated silver ("Application works excellently for 'normal' use").  Version XI isn't listed.  You can view the report at http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=847

Answer (score 2):

Never would be the safest guess.  Their Linux support has always been terrible, and I don't ever expect that to change.  I've found Adobe Acrobat Reader to be quite impressively slow and resource hungry, so finding an alternative may be in your best interest anyway.  I wouldn't be surprised if they just gave up on delivering a reader for the platform.

Have you tried Okular (KDE) or Evince (Gnome)?  I'm not familiar with Reader Extension enabled PDF files, but from a Google search, it appears to just enable a few useful pro features.  On the first PDF form that I found (Form W-4 2014), Okular let me fill it in and run a "Save As..." to retain all my information, however the file did give me an warning/error `"This document has XFA forms, which are currently **unsupported**."`  Okular also supports commenting/markup, but I'm not sure about the other features.

I'm running Linux Mint 16 KDE, and don't want to install a dozen packages just to test Evince.

**Update** [PDF Studio](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/) (paid application w/ free trial) is supposed to support static XFA forms, among many other Acrobat Pro level features.  They have a Linux version and [plans to support LiveCycle XFA forms in version 10 or 11](http://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/?p=705) (currently on 9).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The form I created uses XFA and so far the only PDF reader I have found that supports it in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @Paul PDF Studio may do what you want.  It looks comparable to Acrobat Standard or Professional.  It's a paid application, and I'm not sure what limitations there are on the free trial.